# Finding just one or more comma in a string with ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

How can I detect if a string value only consists of one or more commas and nothing else. The correct value should be something like: ABC,BVC,BNM but sometimes I get value like: , or ,,, or ,, and this is not allowed. How can I detect that a string only have one or more commas and then I can create a warning to the user and stop the process.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `listToArray()` and `arrayToList()` to remove the empty items from the list and can then compare the sanitized version with the original like this:

```
<cfset originalInput = trim( ",,," )>
<cfset sanitizedInput = arrayToList( listToArray( originalInput, ",", false ), "," )>

<!--- Compare both --->
<cfif originalInput NEQ sanitizedInput>

  <!--- Throw error --->

</cfif>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how much your input may vary, but as you currently describe it:

Something as simple as `<cfif MyVar contains ",,">` would work.

If one comma (and nothing else) is a possibility, then

```
<cfif MyVar contains ",," OR Len(MyVar) lt 2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming any non-commas are either letters or numbers, you can do use a regular expression:

```
patternAlphaNumeric = "[0-9a-zA-Z]";
testString = ",,,";

if (reFind(",", testString) > 0 && refind(patternAlphaNumeric, testString) == 0)
code for all commas
else
code for other characters
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only concerned about detecting commas (or one or more of any character), just use ListLen().

- It's a native ColdFusion function.
- It ignores empty list items by default.
- Its default delimiter is a comma.

So, if **your_string** consists only of one or more commas, then **ListLen( your_string )** will always return 0.

Heads up, it also returns 0 for an empty string, so if you don't want your code to pop for empty strings, be sure to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfset local.myString = "string-goes-here">
<cfset local.myNewString = ReReplace(trim(local.myString),",","","ALL")>
<cfif not len(local.myNewString)>
    <!--- warning to the user and stop the process --->
</cfif>
```